# Is this possible in Jquery infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

So I need to grab a ton of content to throw in a function. Now I get a max of 10 items per page, so when I use infinite scroll, the following will load 10 items at a time:

```
$content.infinitescroll({
  navSelector    : '#page-nav',  
  nextSelector   : '#page-nav a',
  itemSelector   : '.entry, .entry_photo'
});
```

**So how can I make it so that I can run my function through lets say 100 items at once instead of 10?**

That means that I cannot just trigger the load 10 times to get 100, I need to load the 100 all at the same time.

Comment: Seems like you need to make that change on the server instead...

Comment: I don't have access to the server, does that mean this is impossible?